# Help with ultra power saving mode bug

Tags: samsung, battery, samsung-galaxy-s, samsung-galaxy-s-5, bugs

I have a Samsung Galaxy S5 with a major problem. One night while turning the phone to Ultra Power Saving Mode the phone immediately shut down. I left the phone o charge and the next morning I woke up the whole entire phone system was gray, it had no color, I thought this was just a glitch so I left the phone to at least make it settle but afterward that it was still gray and had no color, I had access to all my apps but it was just that everything was gray. I have restarted the phone and removed the SD card multiple times but nothing seems to work. I have even gone into settings and tried turning on Emergency mode but nothing happens. Kindly please help me with my problem and sorry about my grammar as English isn't my first language. Have a nice day